# Axis direction of Android cellphone

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am confused of the axis direction of android cellphone. By google, the defination of three axis is as following.
"The X axis is horizontal and points to the right, the Y axis is vertical and points up and the Z axis points towards the outside of the front face of the screen."
So I think this means that if I put my cellphone on a flat table and screen up, than I should record a negative Z value because gravity is pointing down, right? However, no matter I used an app or my own code, I can only get a positive Z value. Same things happen on the other 2 axises. Can anyone help to explain this thing．I tried this on 3 different cellphones, Nexus4, Nexus5 and HTC One. Thanks。

Comment: What are you trying to record? The force of gravity is pulling on you, that is a positive force. If it was pushing on it it would be a negative gravitational force.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/images/axis_device.png

Comment: I'm having this same problem, and I can't wrap my head around it. I'm ok with downwards accelerations being considered positive, but then why is the positive direction of the axis pointing upwards? Did you get an answer?

Comment: @AmiguelS Yes I think I understand that now. You can draw a sketch of the accelerometer with a mass and two springs connected to it. When you move this system to one direction, let's define that as the positive direction, watch the change of the two springs. Then you put the system still vertically and imagine the change of the springs. You will find even the gravity goes down, the value should be up. The difference is moving and staying still. If you still feel a little confused, then I can draw a figure for you. Hope this helps.